# Сохранение данных массива в текстовый файл и чтение из файла

Tags: алгоритм, файлы, pascal, циклы, процедуры

Есть записи tAuto, tOption и массив от tAuto

```
type
tOption=record
ID: integer;
Name: string[40];
end;

tAuto=record
Mark: string[20];
Model: string[20];
Colour: string[20];
Price: integer;
Options: Array[1..3] of tOption;
end;

tCars= array of tAuto;
```

Нужно написать две процедуры:

1)написать код для считывания элементов данного массива в текстовый файл корня папки с программой

2)вторая процедура должна отвечать за вывод сохранённых данных из файла в пустой массив консоли

Мои попытки осущесть задуманное:

```
Procedure SaveInFile(var Cars: tCars);
Var
f: text;
i: integer;
Begin
AssignFile(f,'sort.txt');
Rewrite(f);
for i:= low(cars) to high(cars) do
write(f, cars[i]);
close(f);
End;

Procedure OpenFile(var Cars: tCars);
Var
f: file of tAuto;
i,l: integer;
Begin
AssignFile(f,'sort.txt');
Reset(f);
l := FileSize(f);
SetLength(Cars,l);
for i:= 0 to l-1 do
read(f, cars[i]);
close(f);
End;
```

Итог: компилятор не выдаёт никаких ошибок, не сохраняет файл и ничего не выводит.
Укажите, пожалуйста, что нужно исправить/переписать, чтобы код выполнял свою функцию

Comment: Это так не работает, придётся ручками каждую запись разбирать на поля и записывать в тестовый файл. И так же считывать. Сделайте процедуры типа `WriteOption(t: text; opt: toption);` и `WriteAuto(t: text; auto: tauto);` и дальше в цикле вызывайте их.

Comment: Не могли бы Вы продемонстрировать, как это записывается, пожалуйста?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну вот пример, как сохранять и загружать. Т.к. пример, то никакой обработки ошибок не предусмотрено.

```
program textwrite;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

type
  tOption=record
    ID: integer;
    Name: string[40];
  end;

  tAuto=record
    Mark: string[20];
    Model: string[20];
    Colour: string[20];
    Price: integer;
    Options: Array[1..3] of tOption;
  end;

procedure WriteAuto(const t: text; const auto: tAuto);

  procedure WriteOption(const opt: tOption);
  begin
    WriteLn(t, opt.id, #9, opt.Name);
  end;

var
  index: Integer;
begin
  WriteLn(t, auto.Mark);
  WriteLn(t, auto.Model);
  WriteLn(t, auto.Colour);
  WriteLn(t, auto.Price);
  for index := Low(auto.Options) to High(auto.Options) do
    WriteOption(auto.Options[index]);
end;

procedure ReadAuto(const t: text; var auto: tAuto);

  procedure ReadOption(var opt: tOption);
  var
    Text: string;
    Tab: Integer;
    Code: Integer;
  begin
    ReadLn(t, Text);
    Tab := Pos(#9, text);
    val(copy(text, 1, Tab - 1), opt.ID, Code);
    opt.Name := Copy(Text, Tab + 1, Length(Text));
  end;

var
  index: Integer;
begin
  ReadLn(t, auto.Mark);
  ReadLn(t, auto.Model);
  ReadLn(t, auto.Colour);
  ReadLn(t, auto.Price);
  for index := Low(auto.Options) to High(auto.Options) do
    ReadOption(auto.Options[index]);
end;


const
  Cars: array [0..1] of tAuto = (
    (Mark: 'Nissan'; Model: 'Sentra'; Colour: 'Red'; Price: 100500; Options:
      ((Id: 1; Name: 'Pedals'), (Id: 2; Name: 'Railings'), (Id: 3; Name: ''))),
    (Mark: 'Renault'; Model: 'Logan'; Colour: 'Blue'; Price: 10600; Options:
      ((Id: 1; Name: 'Driver'), (Id: 2; Name: ''), (Id: 3; Name: ''))));

var
  index: Integer;
  f: text;
  loaded: array [0..1] of tAuto;
begin
// сохранение
  AssignFile(f,'sort.txt');
  Rewrite(f);
  for index := Low(Cars) to High(Cars) do
    WriteAuto(f, Cars[index]);
  Close(f);
// загрузка
  AssignFile(f,'sort.txt');
  Reset(f);
  for index := Low(Cars) to High(Cars) do
    ReadAuto(f, loaded[index]);
  Close(f);
  ReadLn;
end.
```

Алгоритм работы простой:
    Сначала мы в цикле для каждого автомобиля вызываем процедуру `WriteAuto()`, которая сохраняет каждое поле записи TAuto в отдельную строку файла. Затем она,  в свою очередь, для каждой опции вызывает `WriteOption()`, которая сохраняет в тот же файл опцию (для разнообразия ID и Name пишутся в одну строку, разделяются табулятором).
    Для загрузки используются соответственно `ReadAuto()` и `ReadOption()`. `ReadOption` после считывания строки из файла разбивает её на две части по символу табуляции и присваивает значения соответствующим полям записи tOption.
    Функция Val() преобразует строку с цифрами в число, вместо неё можно использовать `opt.ID := IntToStr(copy(text, 1, Tab - 1));`.
    При загрузке из такого файла необходимо точно знать сколько в нём записей (размер массива для загрузки). Ну или можно количество записей записывать/считывать перед считыванием остальных данных.

PS: #9 - это символ Tab, предполагается что в названии опций он не встречается.
PS: Писано на Delphi, чистого паскаля под рукой нет.

Comment: Не могли бы Вы пояснить, как работает Ваша программа. У меня в Pascal ABC она не компилируется, выдаёт ошибку: 
Program1.pas(44) : Ошибка времени выполнения: Индекс и длина должны указывать на позицию в строке. Имя параметра: length
В строке: opt.Name := Copy(Text, Tab + 1, MaxInt);

Comment: `Copy(Text, Tab + 1, MaxInt)` - копирует содержимое строки с позиции `Tab + 1` до конца строки. Попробуйте вместо `MaxInt` написать `Length(Text)` [исправил ответ].

Comment: Теперь код компилируется, но ничего не выводит и не сохраняет файл

Comment: Если у вас даже файл не появляется, то попробуйте указать имя файла с полным путём: не `'sort.txt'`, а, например, `'c:\sort.txt'` и поискать его там.

Comment: Я пробовал и так, и так. Файл с программой лежит в отдельной папке. При сохранении и компиляции текстовый файл нигде не создаётся

Comment: Тогда у вас проблема с самим паскалем, потому что создаваться файл должен (если нет никаких ошибок).

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69894/discussion-between-a-hall-and-alekcvp).

Comment: Напишите, пожалуйста, как данный код реализовать в процедурах, которые вызываются из меню, появляющегося в начале программы? С меню всё понятно. Но как оформить сохранение и загрузку в отдельные процедуры?