# Загрузка данных из файла в массив

Tags: pascal, циклы, процедуры

Есть код из ответов предыдущего вопроса: [предыдущий вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/755265/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D1%85%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D0%B2-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB-%D0%B8-%D1%87%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%B0/755402?noredirect=1#comment1166854_755402)

Нужно сделать вывод данных из файла через процедуру, вызываемую в меню программы. Вроде, всё должно работать. Но программа не считывает данные из файла и не выводит их на экран. Подскажите, где ошибка? Может, нужно создать ещё один пустой массив и в него заполнить данные из файла?

```
type
tOption=record
ID: integer;
Name: string[40];
end;

tAuto=record
Mark: string[20];
Model: string[20];
Colour: string[20];
Price: integer;
Options: Array[1..3] of tOption;
end;

tCars= array of tAuto;

procedure WriteAuto(const t: text; const auto: tAuto);

procedure WriteOption(const opt: tOption);
begin
WriteLn(t, opt.id, #9, opt.Name);
end;

var
index: Integer;
begin
WriteLn(t, auto.Mark);
WriteLn(t, auto.Model);
WriteLn(t, auto.Colour);
WriteLn(t, auto.Price);
for index := Low(auto.Options) to High(auto.Options) do
WriteOption(auto.Options[index]);
end;

procedure ReadAuto(const t: text; var auto: tAuto);

procedure ReadOption(var opt: tOption);
var
Text: string;
Tab: Integer;
Code: Integer;
begin
ReadLn(t, Text);
Tab := Pos(#9, text);
val(copy(text, 1, Tab - 1), opt.ID, Code);
opt.Name := Copy(Text, Tab + 1, Length(Text));
end;

var
index: Integer;
begin
ReadLn(t, auto.Mark);
ReadLn(t, auto.Model);
ReadLn(t, auto.Colour);
ReadLn(t, auto.Price);
for index := Low(auto.Options) to High(auto.Options) do
ReadOption(auto.Options[index]);
end;


const
Cars: array [0..1] of tAuto = (
 (Mark: 'Nissan'; Model: 'Sentra'; Colour: 'Red'; Price: 100500; Options:
   ((Id: 1; Name: 'Pedals'), (Id: 2; Name: 'Railings'), (Id: 3; Name: ''))),
 (Mark: 'Renault'; Model: 'Logan'; Colour: 'Blue'; Price: 10600; Options:
   ((Id: 1; Name: 'Driver'), (Id: 2; Name: ''), (Id: 3; Name: ''))));

Procedure TypeAutos(var Cars: tCars); //вывод списка
Var
i,j: integer;
Begin
Writeln();
Writeln('     Список авто');
for i := 0 to high(cars) do
begin
Writeln('Марка: ',Cars[i].Mark);
Writeln('Модель: ',Cars[i].Model);
Writeln('Цвет: ',Cars[i].Colour);
Writeln('Цена: ',Cars[i].Price);
for j := 1 to 3 do begin
Write('Опция номер ',Cars[i].Options[j].ID, ': ');
Write(Cars[i].Options[j].Name);
Writeln();
end;
Writeln();
end;
End;

Procedure SaveInFile (var Cars: tCars);
var
index: Integer; 
f: text;
begin
AssignFile(f,'C:\Users\79654\Desktop\804\sort.txt');
Rewrite(f);
for index := Low(Cars) to High(Cars) do
WriteAuto(f, Cars[index]);
Close(f);
end;

 Procedure OpenFile (var Cars: tCars);
 var
 index: Integer;
 f: text;
 loaded: array [0..1] of tAuto;
 begin
 AssignFile(f,'C:\Users\79654\Desktop\804\sort.txt');
 Reset(f);
 for index := Low(Cars) to High(Cars) do
 ReadAuto(f, loaded[index]);
 Close(f);
 TypeAutos(Cars);
 ReadLn;
 end;

var 
x: integer;
Cars: tCars;
begin
Writeln('Введите значение x: ');
readln(x);
if x = 1 then
SaveInFile(Cars);
if x = 2 then
OpenFile(Cars);
end.
```

Comment: Что такое tCars? Тип не определен

Comment: tCars= array of tAuto; [дописал в вопрос]

Comment: пример работы с потоками ввода вывода
http://vernadsky.tstu.ru/pdf/2011/04/20.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Собственно, учитывая мой комментарий, нужно исправить всего лишь пару моментов: вместо `writeln()` надо писать `writeln('')`, убрать константу `Cars`, убрать лишние `const` - калька с C-подобного языка, видимо.

Но зачем так сложно? Буфер вы не создаете, потоки не используете, более того, ваш record имеет постоянный размер, так и используйте типизированный файл.
Например, так:

```
type
   CarsFile = file of tAuto;

procedure WriteAuto(filename:string; ar_auto: tCars);
var
  f:CarsFile;
  i:integer;

begin
  Assign(f,filename); // привязываем имя файла к переменной
  Rewrite(f);  // открываем файл на запись 
  for I := Low(ar_auto) to High(ar_auto) do write(f,ar_auto[i]); // цикл по массиву, сбрасываем каждый член массива в файл
  Close(f); // закрываем файл
end;

procedure LoadAuto(filename:string; var ar_auto: tCars);
var
  f:CarsFile;
  i:integer;
  au:tAuto;

begin
  Assign(f,filename);
  Reset(f); // открываем файл на чтение
  while not EOF(f) do // циклим до конца файла
    begin
     read(f,au); // читаем запись
     SetLength(ar_auto,length(ar_auto)+1); // выделяем доп. память под массив, можно придумать более хитрый механизм
     ar_auto[High(ar_auto)]:=au; // добавляем новый член к массиву
    end;
  Close(f);
end;
```

Comment: А как вызывать процедуру из меню? Какую команду прописывать? WriteAuto(filename,Cars);?

Comment: WriteFile('имя_файла.avt', переменная tCars); и так же LoadFile('имя_файла.avt', переменная tCars); имя файл и расширение могут быть любыми - сами придумайте. Имя файла можно передавать и в виде переменной.

Comment: Да, имя файла можно еще передать через командную строку - ParamStr(1)

Comment: Прошу прощения - WriteAuto('имя_файла.avt', переменная tCars); и  LoadAuto('имя_файла.avt', переменная tCars);

Comment: Да, уже разобрался, спасибо большое

Comment: Всё работает, но не могли бы Вы пояснить, как работают Ваши процедуры?

Comment: добавил комментарии к ответу